# Angular 7: No service provided for modal

Tags: angular

I have a service that I am providing in the a component using polymorphism. A child component is attempting to open a modal that requires the morphed service via DI, but says there is no provider.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: GenericRolesService, useExisting: UserRolesService }
  ]
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

The modal component constructor

```
constructor(
  private genericRolesService: GenericRolesService,
  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RoleSelectorComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: RoleSelectorModalInput
) {
```

I suspect that the modal is separated from the DI tree. What is the appropriate way to get the polymorphed service to the modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material Dialog has a config attribute that accepts current `ViewContainerRef`. It then uses its injector to resolve dependencies of the component's constructor.

```
export class UserDetailsComponent {

 constructor(
   public dialog: MatDialog,
   private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
 ) {}

 openModal() {
    this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent, {
      viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef
    });
 }
}
```

I created [Stackblitz demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxjdte) for you.